# How do you deserialize JSON in C# when a JSON variable name is invalid and the root array isn't in Key, Value pairs?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

So normally one would create a class or even nested classes to deserialize most JSON.
Then feed the JSON to Json.Net or some other library.

Well that's what I did, until I ran across this JSON.

```
{
  "USD" : {"15m" : 609.09, "last" : 609.09, "buy" : 606, "sell" : 609.09,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "CNY" : {"15m" : 3783.32, "last" : 3783.32, "buy" : 3764.13, "sell" : 3783.32,  "symbol" : "¥"},
  "JPY" : {"15m" : 62194.06, "last" : 62194.06, "buy" : 61878.54, "sell" : 62194.06,  "symbol" : "¥"},
  "SGD" : {"15m" : 761.65, "last" : 761.65, "buy" : 757.79, "sell" : 761.65,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "HKD" : {"15m" : 4721.51, "last" : 4721.51, "buy" : 4697.55, "sell" : 4721.51,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "CAD" : {"15m" : 663.64, "last" : 663.64, "buy" : 660.28, "sell" : 663.64,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "NZD" : {"15m" : 711.55, "last" : 711.55, "buy" : 707.94, "sell" : 711.55,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "AUD" : {"15m" : 648.34, "last" : 648.34, "buy" : 645.05, "sell" : 648.34,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "CLP" : {"15m" : 337004.93, "last" : 337004.93, "buy" : 335295.25, "sell" : 337004.93,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "GBP" : {"15m" : 362.9, "last" : 362.9, "buy" : 361.06, "sell" : 362.9,  "symbol" : "£"},
  "DKK" : {"15m" : 3356.52, "last" : 3356.52, "buy" : 3339.49, "sell" : 3356.52,  "symbol" : "kr"},
  "SEK" : {"15m" : 4068.99, "last" : 4068.99, "buy" : 4048.35, "sell" : 4068.99,  "symbol" : "kr"},
  "ISK" : {"15m" : 69486.21, "last" : 69486.21, "buy" : 69133.69, "sell" : 69486.21,  "symbol" : "kr"},
  "CHF" : {"15m" : 548.15, "last" : 548.15, "buy" : 545.37, "sell" : 548.15,  "symbol" : "CHF"},
  "BRL" : {"15m" : 1354.87, "last" : 1354.87, "buy" : 1348, "sell" : 1354.87,  "symbol" : "R$"},
  "EUR" : {"15m" : 450.11, "last" : 450.11, "buy" : 447.83, "sell" : 450.11,  "symbol" : "€"},
  "RUB" : {"15m" : 20948.52, "last" : 20948.52, "buy" : 20842.25, "sell" : 20948.52,  "symbol" : "RUB"},
  "PLN" : {"15m" : 1851.37, "last" : 1851.37, "buy" : 1841.98, "sell" : 1851.37,  "symbol" : "zł"},
  "THB" : {"15m" : 19801.3, "last" : 19801.3, "buy" : 19700.84, "sell" : 19801.3,  "symbol" : "฿"},
  "KRW" : {"15m" : 619112.58, "last" : 619112.58, "buy" : 615971.73, "sell" : 619112.58,  "symbol" : "₩"},
  "TWD" : {"15m" : 18274.36, "last" : 18274.36, "buy" : 18181.65, "sell" : 18274.36,  "symbol" : "NT$"}      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that the root array isn't in a name value pair.
2nd is that the "15m" Key isn't a valid C# variable name. (I was planing on doing a string replace to something else but I decided it was too ugly)

Here is the super simple solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Deserializers;

namespace JSONRestTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Requesting data...");

            //create new RestSharp Client and tell it the Host
            RestClient client = new RestClient("http://blockchain.info");

            //Tell it the path and any variables if needed
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/ticker", Method.GET);
            //request.AddParameter("myParameter", myVariable);

            //Tell RestSharp to expect JSON
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            //Execute the request
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            //Create a JSON Deserializer
            JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();

            //Deserialize to a Dictionary Object 
            Dictionary<string, Rate> jsonObj = deserial.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Rate>>(response);

            //Loop through the Dictionary
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Rate> currency in jsonObj)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(currency.Key + " Rate: " + currency.Value.last.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done...");            
        }
    }

    public class Rate
    {        
        public float _15m { get; set; }
        public double last { get; set; }
        public double buy { get; set; }
        public double sell { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
    }      
}
```

The trick is to use Dictionary objects for all of the un-Keyed data. This fixes the first problem.
The next is to use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) and put a "_" infront of the offending variable.